# Composition of functions is Riemann integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I read this theorem in Rudin. I agree that uniform continuous give us inequality with $\delta^{2}$. But I don't know why our choice of $\delta$ give us $M^{*}_{i} - m^{*}_{i} \le \epsilon$. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: You need to show us definition $6.1$, since it has been referenced in this context.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг $6.1$ give us : 
$M_{i} = \sup f(x)$, $m_{i} = \inf f(x)$, where $x_{i - 1} < x < x_{i}$. $U(P,f) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}M_{i}\triangle x_{i}$ and $L(P,f)$ also like that.

Comment: I think the answer here is that $\delta$ can be chosen small enough so that $\delta^2 < \delta$ is also true  (i.e. $\delta < 1$). In that case, what has been said follows. Is that right?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг that's coulb be. But why because of this information we could get : $M^{*}_{i} - m^{*}_{i} < \epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $i\in A,\ M_i-m_i<\delta,\ $ so for all $s,t\in [m_i,M_i], |\phi (t)-\phi (s)|<\epsilon.$

Therefore,

$M_i^*-m^*=\sup_{x\in [x_i,x_{i+1}]}h(x)-\inf_{x\in [x_i,x_{i+1}]}h(x)= \sup_{t\in [m_i,M_{i+1}]}\phi(t)-\inf_{s\in [m_i,M_{i+1}]}\phi(s)\le \epsilon.$